# convert ASp.net membership provider classes to code first entities in entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-5

I am using entity frame work code first approach to design my web application in asp.net 4.5.
I have converted all asp.net membership related tables in code first entities as below

```
public class Application
    {

        public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public System.Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public class Membership
    {
        [ForeignKey("Application")]
        public System.Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
        [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
        public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public int PasswordFormat { get; set; }
        public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string PasswordQuestion { get; set; }
        public string PasswordAnswer { get; set; }
        public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
        public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastLockoutDate { get; set; }
        public int FailedPasswordAttemptCount { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart { get; set; }
        public int FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowsStart { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }

    public class Profile
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
        public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public string PropertyNames { get; set; }
        public string PropertyValueStrings { get; set; }
        public byte[] PropertyValueBinary { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }

    public  class Role
    {
        [ForeignKey("Application")]
        public System.Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public System.Guid RoleId { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public  class User
    {
        [ForeignKey("Application")]
        public System.Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public bool IsAnonymous { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }

        public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
        public virtual Membership Membership { get; set; }
        public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

My Datacontext and initalizer classes are as below

```
 public class TrainningInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TrainningContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(TrainningContext context)
        {

        }

    }

 public partial class TrainningContext : DbContext
    {
        public TrainningContext()
            : base("name=TrainningContext")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }


    }
```

I am setting Initializer as below in application_start event inside Global.asax.

```
Database.SetInitializer<TrainningContext>(new TrainningInitializer());
```

But when I am running my application I am getting below error

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.RoleUsers_dbo.Users_User_UserId' on table 'RoleUsers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

Can someone please help in correcting my entity classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete an `Application` entity this delete cascades to the `Roles` and the `Users` and then from `Roles` to the `RoleUsers` join table and from the `Users` to `RoleUsers`. Those two delete paths from `Application` to `RoleUsers` table are the "multiple cascade paths" the exception is talking about. They are not allowed in SQL Server.

Cascading delete is enabled by default for the `Roles` and `Users` relationships of `Application` because the foreign key `ApplicationId` in these two tables is not nullable, hence the relationship is required. Required relationships have cascading delete turned on by default.

But you can turn it off with Fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Application>()
        .HasMany(a => a.Roles)
        .WithRequired(r => r.Application)
        .HasForeignKey(r => r.ApplicationId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Application>()
        .HasMany(a => a.Users)
        .WithRequired(u => u.Application)
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.ApplicationId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

(It's probably sufficient for one of the two.)

If you would delete an `Application` entity now, you need to delete the related `Roles` and `Users` as well. The database won't do that automatically for you anymore.